# Timer for an iOS game with 4 decimal places. My dev team says it's impossible

Tags: ios, 2d-games

My dev team is creating a game where the winner is timed up to 4 decimal places. So, for example, the winner completes a task in 13.9503 seconds. However, my developers told me that iOS only allows developers to track time up to 3 decimal places. Is this true or are there workarounds?

Thanks!

Comment: This is not at all my field but I *thought* that microsecond resolution was possible. Not sure how accurate it is though - i.e. is it a lower bound on the time, or the real time?

Answer (score 2):

I would like to ask why you are using 4 decimal places, as if you are changing a UILabel 10000 times a second, I wouldn't recommend it, and if you aren't, well then a simple workaround is to use a 3 decimal place timer, and add a random number on the end. Although it sounds like a cheaty method of doing it, no human eye is going to pick up that the 4th decimal place is wrong.

Comment: Good question. We're adding a 4th place because we had a lot of people play the same game (in tens of thousands) at the same time and preferably there should be only one winner. The more decimal places we have the smaller chances of multiple winners at the same time. So instead of two users having the time of 12.432 seconds, we can add that one more step in showing one of them at 12.4327 and the other 12.4329.

Comment: Ok. Good response. May I suggest that because timers fire very inaccurately, it may be dependent on the processing power and speed of the users device, as to how accurately the timer fires, so I would therefore recommend that you try to think of some other system.

Perhaps you could use a random generator to pick the winner if people draw.

Comment: I see. We might look into that in our next version of the app. For now, we'll have to stick with the timer. That said, do you think that your solution of placing a random number at the end of the 3 decimal timer is the only viable solution? Thanks for taking your time!

Comment: No Problem, I like helping people. Yes, I believe that is the best viable solution, and it is unlikely you will get better than that. The reason for this is because for the device to update a timer 10000 times a second when the user is also interacting with other things and emails and messages e.t.c. are being pulled in in the background, it is almost impossible for the device to give an accurate result. If my answer has helped you, be sure to mark it has a correct answer to help other users with the same problem get a quick and easy solution :).

Answer (score 0):

For games your team should consider to use
`func CACurrentMediaTime() -> CFTimeInterval`,
 milliseconds are fractional part of the result.
The number can later be formatted in NSDecimalNumber with fix representation of Decimal.